# Installing devise gem for Rails fails on Raspberry Pi 2 B due to bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, raspberry-pi, bundler

I'm trying to install devise in Rails 6.0.2.1 via `bundle install`. On my computer that works, while when I do it on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, the gem `bcrypt` on version `3.1.13`, which devise depends on, tries to compile itself for x86, while the Raspberry Pi runs on arm, meaning the build fails with the following error message:

```
Fetching bcrypt 3.1.13
Installing bcrypt 3.1.13 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13/ext/mri
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200202-4603-1rqfk3s.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c

// ===========================
// here's the interesting part
// ===========================
gcc  -D__SKIP_GNU  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -c -o x86.o x86.S
x86.S: Assembler messages:
x86.S:202: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
make: *** [<builtin>: x86.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.13 for 
inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/armv7l-linux-eabihf/2.7.0 static/bcrypt-3.1.13/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.13' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeedsm before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  devise-two-factor was resolved to 3.0.3, which depends on
    devise was resolved to 4.6.2, which depends on
      bcrypt
```

When I manually install version 3.1.12, it works. It only doesn't work with 3.1.13. Is there a way to build it manually for the correct architecture and make bundler use that, or any other way to fix this?

Comment: You can use `bundle config build.bcrypt --use-system-libraries` to skip compiling bcrypt. I think you may also be able to set in the ARCHFLAGS in the ENV and it should be used by make. https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: You can try `gem install bcrypt --platform arm-linux`. https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/183232449127ce2bc96b2eb2b1117e9cfb98d0c1/lib/rubygems/commands/help_command.rb#L233

Comment: @max: Sadly, the `--platform` flag didn't do anything. I'm not sure how exactly the ARCHFLAGS for my system would look like, and if that would even change anything, as I couldn't find much about it. Is there a way to completely build the gem from source if all else fails?

Comment: `gem install` builds gems. For plain old ruby gems that just means moving them into right folder. It's actually the C bcrypt library that the bcrypt gem has as a dependency thats failing. You should be able to install it through your OS package manager and use `--use-system-libraries`.

Comment: I have bcrypt installed on my system, yet the same error still occurs, both through bundler and when I try to install the gem on it's own, with and without `--use-system-libraries`.